# IBM Think Pad T40 not booting, screen never lights up.

Tags: boot, troubleshooting, laptop-repair

so i had my buddie drop his old laptop, the display wont light up there seems to be some issues with the boot up. it doesn't seem like it evern starts the process but the start light are acting normally i'm not even sure what the os is. where shoould i start?

Comment: Maybe because he dropped it? Also, if you don't know what's going on or where to begin, why did you offer to fix it in the first place?

Comment: I didnt offer he was ready to trash it so i tgought i would give it a shot. But i have decided to Simply take the hard drive and put it in another computer the only problem is it's an old hard drive and uses the prongs  all my other laptops use SATA conections[picture of IBM hard disk ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyeVT.jpg)
Before i go and but an addapter is there any other method of retriveing data off of this harddisk?